# Using resistor networks as voltage ladder

Tags: resistors, resistor-ladder

Are there resistor networks which could function as a pre-made voltage ladder? In other words are there variations on how the resistor network is assembled, ie in series or parallel? I've found [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/20pcs-Resistor-Network-A09-471G-470-ohm/32436803935.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.6d9edbfekfvgXw&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10130_10068_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10340_10548_10341_10192_10190_10084_10083_10615_10307_10301_10303_10059_10314_10184_10534_100031_10604_10103_10142,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=ff00f5b9-aa08-4107-9b25-dc45a5a6a26b-0&algo_pvid=ff00f5b9-aa08-4107-9b25-dc45a5a6a26b&priceBeautifyAB=5) but am not sure how they are assembled...Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are variations. Sometimes they have one pin common. Sometimes they don't. Other configurations might be possible. These seem to be commoned.

Comment: If you buy from a reputable supplier (DigiKey, Mouser, Farnell...),you can get proper datasheets for the components which will show the various resistor arrangements available.

Comment: Ive had a browse on the more reputable sources but the shipping cost is rather outlandish so it has put me off. i may head back it i am unable to decode the minimal Chinese labelling. thanks.

Comment: What is the cost of the time it takes you to figure out the arrangement of the cheap Chinese ones? And what if it does not suit your design after all? Not to mention the shipping times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typically two arrangements: 
Resistor networks wired together with one common point.
[image]

Or these kinds:

[image]

If you need a ladder, you can buy a network and connect the terminals. Why aren't there more configurations? Because manufacturers don't want to exclude customers options with a more specific configuration.

[image]

Image [source](http://catalog.thedigitalshop.net/resist/rndi.html)

There are also precision networks that have better tolerances and resistor matches in one IC

[image]

The only other place where I think you'd see custom resistor ladders is in the high voltage sector where spacing is important to prevent arcing.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. It seems odd that they dont come in the ladder configuration dont you think? i would have thought it would be quite a popular item. i just want it so i can read my 5-way switch with an analog pin...

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit odd, but since most people use PCB's nowadays its quite simple to mock up a ladder, but not so simple if your prototyping or want one off the shelf for a product. You could have your own made up on a two layer board (http://www.pcbweb.com/) for probably less than 60$ for low quantities and less than 2$ a board for higher quantities